# Lubuntu boot: no signal once in two

Tags: boot, grub2, lubuntu, 15.04, monitor

I have a strange problem with a fresh installation of Lubuntu 15.04 (Ubuntu 11.04 was ok). Sometimes when I boot the computer the monitor goes in "No DVI signal" mode right after grub selection. However, if I unplug the cable and plug it again I can see Lubuntu booting! The same if I press some buttons.

If I push the reset button I won't have the no-signal problem but it will come back at the following boot.

Comment: Open a terminal, type `dmesg > dmesg.log`. Add a pastebin link to the contents of the file here.

Comment: @daltonfury42 here it is http://pastebin.com/p5MT3C33

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to grub press e to edit the GRUB menu. (vmlinuz line)

2.Using the arrow keys to navigate, delete quiet and splash and again insert one of the options below.

For:-
Older Intel video card: i915.modeset=1 or i915.modeset=0

nVidia: nomodeset

Generic: xforcevesa

[AMD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver)

Press Ctrl and X to boot.
The suggested options that I have found are hardware specific. Here is a list:

If this worked every time edit it permanently in ur grub menu.